# Submit form to both code behind and third party url?

Tags: asp.net

I have a legacy app that I need to change to accommodate a new payment processor.
The app is Asp.Net.
Without reconstructing the app (not in the budget) I need to take the final form and save information from it in the code behind, like it currently does, then I need to submit that same form to a third party url. Ideally as one button push to the end user.

I'm drawing a complete blank on a way to do this.  Any suggestions?

---

Forgot to mention that JQuery and javascript are both valid tools for a solution.

Comment: Are both forms exactly identical? I mean, all you need is to change the action URL in the form?

Comment: Just to make sure... The form is currently submitted in the traditionnal, HTML only way? I means, no AJAX there, right?

Comment: Javascript & Jquery are on the table.

Comment: It is submitted to Asp.Net code behind in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

so currently it's saving the results via code?  Well, you could hack it by putting some javascript on the page that read's the forms values and posts them (eg with jquery), before doing you actual asp post.

edit (something like this might help (in some cases):

```
//change the action of the form (you could just change in code or this
$('#myform').attr('action','http://newpaymentproc.com/me/');

//override the default submit
$('#myformsubmitbutton').click(function(){
    //extract the form data somehow (depends on form)
    var formObj;
    $.each($('#myform').find('input').serializeArray(), function(i, field)   {
        formObj[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    //post to old place
    $.post('/old_current.asp', formObj).then(
        //after posting to old place and getting response...
        //submit form to new payment processor
        $('#myform').submit()

    );

    // Cancel the actual form submit click to give time for post
    return false;
});
```

Another way would be to have the legacy code (after submission) spit out a form with the data in it and some javascript to trigger submit on page load.

Comment: Not to foil your efforts, but this question has no reference to jQuery or javascript anywhere in it.

Comment: It won't work if the form is submited by regular POST, since the browser would then be redirected to the target page of the first submission page.

Comment: @jwatkins I'm suggesting posting via ajax to one location (the old place) and when the ok is received, posting and redirecting to the new place.  I think it's possible.   the response to the ajax request would be "the page html" that used to show (if any) when submitting.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a javascript function that's bound to the form submit button's click event, or the form's submit event. The function will need to prevent the default form submission from firing. Use jQuery to serialize the form data, and create a synchronous AJAX request to submit the data to the third party. After the ajax submission has completed, you can trigger the form submission to the code-behind. If the ajax fails to submit properly, you can optionally abort the form submission to the code-behind.

You may need to account for XSS security, so look into cross-origin resource sharing and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Another option would be to have the code-behind behave as an http client and submit the form data to the third party.

Answer (score 0):

After the original process has completed, just take the submitted form data and push it to whichever URL you're working with. It requires minimal modification on the original app.

I have no code to go on, so I have no code to give. Hope that helps!